# How to format payload for Kartra API in Python

Tags: python, php, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to make an API post call to this Kartra Inbound API using Python requests.post.  Here is my Python code:

```
 payload = { 
    'api_key': settings.KARTRA_API_KEY,
    'api_password': settings.KARTRA_API_PASSWORD,
    'app_id': settings.KARTRA_APP_ID,
    'lead': {
        'email': 'joe@joe.com',
        'first_name': 'Joseph',
        'last_name': 'Smith'
    },
    'actions': {
        '0': {'cmd': 'search_lead'}
    }
}
url = settings.KARTRA_API_URL
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

The only example I have to follow is in PHP (which I haven't worked with).  It goes like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
http_build_query(
    array(
        'app_id' => 'AIm863DwsOW',
        'api_key' => 'QG9GPLW8G',
        'api_password' => 'kdwFAfwrfVS',
        'lead' => array(
            'id' => '3232323223', //you may pass either ID or EMAIL. If both, the system will pick ID
            'email' => 'JoeSmith@domain.com',     
        ),
        'actions' => array(
            '0' => array(
                   'cmd' => 'search_lead',
             ),
        )
  )
)
);
```

All I can get is an error like this:

> {"status":"Error","message":"'actions' not an array","type":"224"}

I've validated that my keys and tokens appear to be working correctly.

I've tried everything I can think of to get the endpoint to interpret the 'actions' as an array.  Can someone please set me straight?  MUCH appreciated as I have wasted literally hours messing with this.

Comment: So, for anyone else who might see this...I have been around and around with the "support" team from Kartra and all I get is links to the inadequate docs I've already read and patronizing lectures about it being my responsibility to make my own code work!  No Kidding?  Thanks, you've been helpful.  They did point out that my email for the lead above must end in @kartra.com in test mode.  Tried that and the error was the same.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comments, Kartra support was no help. Soo... I took the PHP example and sent it to https://httpbin.org/post to find out what was actually being sent.  That was a revelation in and of itself (never knew about tools like this).

Here's a link to the example in PHP: https://documentation.kartra.com/section-28-php-sample-creating-a-lead/

Here's what is actually sent to the api:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "actions[0][cmd]": "create_lead", 
    "actions[1][cmd]": "assign_tag", 
    "actions[1][tag_name]": "My customer", 
    "api_key": "QG9GPLW8G", 
    "api_password": "kdwFAfwrfVS", 
    "app_id": "AIm863DwsOW", 
    "lead[custom_fields][0][field_identifier]": "text1", 
    "lead[custom_fields][0][field_value]": "text message", 
    "lead[custom_fields][1][field_identifier]": "dropdown1", 
    "lead[custom_fields][1][field_value]": "612", 
    "lead[custom_fields][2][field_identifier]": "checkbox1", 
    "lead[custom_fields][2][field_value][0]": "620", 
    "lead[custom_fields][2][field_value][1]": "621", 
    "lead[email]": "JoeSmith@domain.com", 
    "lead[first_name]": "Joe", 
    "lead[last_name]": "Smith"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Content-Length": "678", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5f77604a-7b5fee841e85d78f6b352133"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "104.14.117.45", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Here is the actual working Python code for a test:

```
payload = { 
    'api_key': settings.KARTRA_API_KEY,
    'api_password': settings.KARTRA_API_PASSWORD,
    'app_id': settings.KARTRA_APP_ID,
    'lead[email]': 'joe@kartra.com',
    'lead[first_name]': 'Joe',
    'lead[last_name]': 'Smith',
    'actions[0][cmd]': 'create_lead',
}

url = settings.KARTRA_API_URL
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
```

Another point I learned from this is that the requests.post() library does not do a deep copy below the second level of a Python dict of dicts of dicts.  See my original question for more...

I truly hope this helps someone avoid the pain I had to go through to figure this out.  Admittedly, it would have been easier if I knew more about Python, HTTP, and PHP and had not tried to avoid standing up PHP to test the example code.  Live and learn!

Comment: This was extremely helpful, was banging my head on the desk for a couple of days, thanks!

Comment: My pleasure.  This took me literally a couple days to figure out.  I was ready to scream.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Thanks, tried so much but all invain, but afterall found your method. But I am trying to use search_lead, it only works with id, but doesn't work with email address, same issue with get_lead, only works with id, and not with email

Answer (score 0):

If the error is simple as `'actions' not an array` then that could only mean one thing- `actions aren't given as an array`. In Python, arrays are enclosed by `[]` square brackets, and curly braces `{}` are used for the `dictionary` data structure.

Simple changing the actions part as an array should solve the issue

```
'actions': [
    {
        0: {'cmd': 'search_lead'}
    }
]
```

The verbose API also explains the cause of the error [here](https://documentation.kartra.com/section-25-system-ping-back-confirmation-messages/).

Comment: Thanks for replying.  First off, not valid Python syntax so it won't run.  Second, I looked at the referenced page and all it says is that the item is not an array.  It's an exact repeat of the actual error message.

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code:

```
       'actions' => array(
            '0' => array(
                   'cmd' => 'search_lead',
             ),
```

Can be interpreted as a `list` or `dict`, you can try to "translate" the PHP bit to this:

```
'actions': [
    {
        'cmd': 'search_lead'
    }
]
```

---

**edit:**.
What if you try:

```
'actions': [
    {
        0: {'cmd': 'search_lead'}
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help.  Tried it and exact same result.  If I look at the '0' it looks like they require it as a key to the array.  I expected a different response from the API based on your suggestion.  Exactly the same.

Comment: added another try in this post @BillHuang

Comment: No joy.  I've tried all of these.  Can't even make it work in Postman with [].  No IDEA what they want here.  No docs that help either.  Thanks again for trying.  My research shows that CURL wants to urlencode everything.  Tried that too.  They treat JSON coming in or urlencoded as an attack and block it.

Comment: ok sorry I'm not a good help, might be worth trying to urlencode the payload. but what if you try to use the `json` parameter in the `requests.post` method? `response = requests.post(url, json=payload)`

Comment: Tried both of those. No Joy.  Waiting to hear from their support.  Will update the thread *when* I crack this!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Kartra's API gave me tons of trouble but here's a working Python script:

```
import requests
payload = { 
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'api_password': API_PW,
    'app_id': API_ID,
    'lead[email]': 'TESTTESTTEST@me.com',
    'lead[first_name]': 'Joe',
    'lead[last_name]': 'Smith',
    'actions[0][cmd]': 'create_lead',
}

url = 'https://app.kartra.com/api'
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(response)
print(response.text)
```

I wasn't able to get this working in Postman until I set the
Content-Type: x-www-form-urlencoded

Which formats it as described in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073451/15195663

Thus the RAW post body actually ends up looking like this (this works in Postman as-is with the content-type header added):

app_id=API_ID&api_key=API_KEY&api_password=API_PW&lead%5Bemail%5D=TESTTESTTEST%40me.com&lead%5Bfirst_name%5D=Joe&lead%5Blast_name%5D=Smith&actions%5B0%5D%5Bcmd%5D=create_lead

FYI If anyone is trying to get GoHighLevel's webhook to call Kartra to create a user, you can't since GHL only accepts JSON in as-is. Try through Zapier instead.